# Why does PCKS1-v1.5 signing require DER wrapping?

Tags: rsa, pkcs1

Reading RFC3447, [Section 8.2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3447#section-8.2.1), primitive RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN requires an encoding into ASN.1/DER. Why not just sign the raw hash bytes rather then wrapping them as ASN1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASN.1 wrapper includes the `digestAlgorithm` field, which explicitly specifies which hash algorithm was used. Without that, the verifier would have to try to infer the algorithm, which would seem like an open invitation to vulnerabilities.